# Scala playfamework - how to wrap one JSON string with another?

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I have JSON data coming from two different API endpoints. The first JSON contains data about stores and the second contains data on transactions(sales).

For each store Id I'm getting an array of transactions and parsing it into `JsValue`. So I have a `store` Jsvalue representing the certain store and `transactions` JsValue, representing an array of transactions for the store. Then I stringify the JsValues:

```
(Json.stringify(storeJsValue), Json.stringify(transactionsJson))
```

Printed result of the stringified JsValues for the above Array[(String, String)]:

```
({"store_id":"01","name":"Store_1"}, [{"saleId": 12, "name": "New name1", "saleType": "New Type1"]}, {"saleId": 222, "name": "Some name1", "saleType": "SomeType5"})
({"store_id":"02","name":"Store_2"}, [{"saleId": 123, "name": "New name2", "saleType": "New Type2"}])
({"store_id":"03","name":"Store_3"}, [{"saleId": 1234, "name": "New name3", "saleType": "New Type3"}, {"saleId": 333, "name": "Some name3", "saleType": "SomeType3"}])
```

Finally I want to produce a resulting string so that the store data wraps its transactions data and looks like this:

```
"{store:\"storeJson\",transactions:\"+ transactionsJson + "}"
```

What is the best way to achieve this with Play Json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to achieve the desired result.

```
val store = Json.stringify(storeJsValue)
val transactions = Json.stringify(transactionsJsValue)
val storeWithTransactions: String = s"{store: $store , transactions: $transactions}"
```

This way I'm getting a string with data on a store and all its transactions. So I just iterate over stores and for each store Id get its transactions from another endpoint. Then concatenate stringified JsValues of `store` and `transactions` collecting the resulting Strings into Array[String].

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be converting the jsons to objects, create a new object with the attributes "store" and "transactions" and transform it to JSON again.

That way you would get:

```
{ 
  "store": {
    "store_id":"01",
    "name":"Store_1"
  },
  "transactions": [
    {
        "saleId": 12,
        "name": "New name1",
        "saleType": "New Type1"
    }, 
    {
        "saleId": 222,
        "name": "Some name1", 
        "saleType": "SomeType5"
    }
  ]
}
```

Your class:

```
case class MyClass( store : Store, transactions : Array[Sales]) {
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you have two json values, you can make a new object out of them:

```
val storeWithTransactions: String = Json.stringify(Json.obj(
       "store" -> storeJsValue,
       "transactions" -> transactionsJsValue))
```

Comment: I have provided a similar solution below and it solved the problem. Could you tell what is the advantage of your approach, creating an object instead of concatenating strings? When may it be helpful?

Comment: in my approach, the result must be a valid JSON. when concatenating strings a "bug" / "mistake" can result in an invalid json.

Answer (score 1):

In Play you can use the Json `Reads/Writes` helpers to convert from a `case class` to `Json` and vice versa. So, for your example:

```
case class Store(store_id: String, name: String)
```

Then if you have a Json and want to turn it into `Store` case class you need a 'reader':

```
val storeReads: Reads[Store] = Json.reads[Store]
```

After that you can read the content of Json as a String and turn it into the case class (assuming `storeJson` is a val that contains the content of Json):

```
val toStoreCaseClass: JsResult[Store] = Json.fromJson[Store](json.parse(storeJson))
```

If you want to turn the case class into Json, then you use writes:

```
val storeWrites: OWrites[Store] = Json.writes[Store]
```

Now assume that you have a val `storeInstance` of type `Store`, you turn it into Json, by the following line:

```
Json.toJson(storeInstance)
```

You can do the same thing for transactions.

Ok Now that you have case classes, you can morph them into whatever format you want by using the usual collections commands (e.g., `map`, `filter`, etc.). You can even have an additional more generic case class that holds the format you want to achieve (with its read/writes); and do your data operations, and then at last turn them into Json.